# My dog has odd circles of lighter skin on either side of his face. Can anyone tell me what they are?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition

My 5 year old lab has these odd circles on both sides of his mouth. He has had them for several months and I've assumed it was due to allergies. In the last week the circles have gotten significantly more pronounced and now seem raised around the edges. Does anyone recognize this?[image]

Comment: I am not a vet and have no experience with it,, but my SWAG is ringworm (a fungal infection)

Comment: We wondered about ringworm but he has had this for several months and I would think we would have also gotten ringworm.

Comment: Looks like infection/scarring of some sort, in any case. Vet can tell you more.

Comment: Agreed. He goes in tomorrow, so fingers crossed 

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but there seem to be two more lesions below the eye where the hair is thinner and the skin shines through. That makes me think an infection is more likely than an allergy. However, I have no idea which kind of infection. Could be a fungus like ringworm, could be parasites like mites. Search his bed / pillow for any residue like fine black or brown sand or dust (that would indicate parasites).